# PowerShell Create a series in System.Object (PSCustomObject)

Tags: powershell

Is there an easier way to accomplish this without typing the series out? I tried some ideas with arrays and dereferencing, but nothing ended up working.

```
$rowP = "" | Select-Object Course,"5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the following approach.

1. Create an ordered dictionary:

```
$properties = [ordered]@{
  Course = $null
}
```

2. Use the `..` range operator to generate the range of integers 5 through 35, add empty entries to the dictionary:

```
5..35 |ForEach-Object {
  $properties["${_}"] = $null
}
```

3. Convert the dictionary to a PSCustomObject:

```
$object = [pscustomobject]$properties
```

---

Alternatively, you could also use the range operator to generate the integer range and pass those as property names to `Select-Object`:

```
"" |Select-Object -Property @('Course'; 5..35 -as [string[]])
```

Comment: "" |Select-Object -Property @('Course'; 5..35 -as [string[]]) This is what I was experimenting with but I was attempting to cast 5..35, like Course,[string[]] (5..35) and did not use the "Course"; at all. Thanks, this give good insight into where I was going wrong.

Comment: @BrianMcMahon You're welcome! Bareword arguments (strings without quotation marks) only work in argument mode (when you're passing a literal argument to a command basically). Check out the [`about_Parsing` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing) for more details :)